# Sum of Total Billed for last month and this month in a single SQL query

Tags: sql

I don't really know what to try, even, but we need to show a column for last month's total billing and another column for this month's total billing. Currently, we show just the total billing to date.

Here is what we have so far:

> SELECT
>       MAX(JCCM.JCCo) as [Company], 
>       JCCM.Contract as [Contract], 
>       JCCM.ContractAmt as [Contract Amount], 
>       JCCM.BilledAmt as [Billed Amount],
>       JCCM.ContractAmt - JCCM.BilledAmt as [Remaining Amount]
>       FROM 
>       JCCM 
>       INNER JOIN PMOI 
>       ON PMOI.PMCo=JCCM.JCCo AND PMOI.Project = JCCM.Contract 
>       WHERE 
>       JCCM.JCCo=1 AND PMOI.PMCo=1 AND JCCM.Contract LIKE '2%' 
>       GROUP BY JCCM.JCCo, JCCM.Contract, JCCM.ContractAmt, JCCM.BilledAmt

The [Billed Amount] pulls the total billed to date correctly, but we need to do two separate columns, one for the previous month total and then this month's total.

Comment: How is `JCCM.BilledAmt` populated? Is there a table that contains the billing detail by date?

Comment: What predicate in the query relates to this month?

Comment: JCCM.BilledAmt is a field in our Viewpoint software. There doesn't seem to be a date tied to a billed amount here, but there is one in another table, which I should be able to inner join and use that date as a reference if need be.

Comment: WHat database are you using here?   Date expressions vary between databases

Comment: I'm not sure. I've just always used it for building reports in Crystal and SQL statements. I'm not a DB person (obviously). How would I find that out?

Comment: does this  field JCCM.BilledAmt give you the total amount for current month? if so, are you able to get linking another table the total amount for month prior?

Comment: No, it's not per month. It is the total billed for whatever date parameter it is given (sometimes no parameter, so forever).